# How can I make a slideshow using HTML, CSS, and Javascript displaying an app's images on an image of an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I have so far

[image]

This is the code that I used to get this image on there:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="index.css"/>
      <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="slider">
  </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

and here is the CSS I used for my div "slider" class

```
.slider{
background-image: url('images/background.png');
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

So how can I make a div **INSIDE** of this div, which will allow me to display a slideshow of my app's images? I want it to be very similar to these websites:

1. shazam.com
2. instagram.com
3. venmo.com

I don't know how to *fit* these images the right way, can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about something like this

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Grezzo/86soo0ea/2/)

```js
var $canvas
$(function(){
  $canvas=$("div.canvas")
   setInterval(scroll, 5000);
});
function scroll(){
  if ($canvas.position().left!=-1195){
    $canvas.animate({left: "-=239"});
  }else{
    $canvas.animate({left: 0});
  }
}
```

```css
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 31px;
  top: 122px;
  width: 239px;
  height: 342px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 2195px;
  height: 342px;
}
.page {
  width: 239px;
  height: 342px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://d3sq5bmi4w5uj1.cloudfront.net/images/brochure/apps/iphone.png">
<div class="mask">
  <div class="canvas">
    <div class="page" style="background: red;"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="page" style="background: blue;"><img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```